# Can anyone explain this code in string formatting?

Tags: python-3.x

```
print(f'{"jane":^10} {"marry":^10} {"paul":^10} {"jhon":^10}')
print(f'{"*":^10} {"*":^10} {"*":^10} {"*":^10}'
```

can anyone tell me what happens with the ":^10" in this code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The curly braces surround the string parts which are to be formatted, and the parts after the colon specify how they are formatted. The caret specifies that the text will be centered, and the 10 specifies that that part of the formatted string will be 10 characters.